# Why channel closed automatically

Tags: core-lightning

I got this message:

I tried looking in the logs. Just prior to the channel closing, seems like
there was a temporary network issue and the re-establishment message wasn't 
received by your node. Waited 5 minutes for a reply before our nodes retried 
(successfully) to re-connect. But I guess by then it was too late, the channel 
was already closed. What do you logs say?

Log Summary:

12:33    Received re-establishment message from remote side for channel
12:38:02 Disconnecting 220.133.223.206:9735, reason: Peer 220.133.223.206:9735 no answer for 5m0s -- disconnecting
12:38:04 Established connection to: 220.133.223.206:9735
12:39    CNCT: Unprompted commitment broadcast for ChannelPoint

Longer log summary 
2019-02-13 12:33:01.877 [INF] HSWC: Received re-establishment message from remote side for channel(624919015402f01fd46d6c0d57a3ac23ed33dc411c6f6b395c117867fba0b4fc:0)

====
How can I figure out whats going on?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my LND node closing channels?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84272/why-is-my-lnd-node-closing-channels)

Comment: Rene, you are the expert, I don't understand it at all. I have no idea what I can do. Its a pitty, since only this channel seemed to contribute to collected fees. The link only tells me it can happen, but does not explain me how to defeat it.